# Using API v2 of WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

EDIT:
Incase anyone is reading this, I made this post before the v2 api was documented, however documentation is now available, so if you're having issues, refer to: http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#introduction

---

I'm trying to update the PHP REST API client library found here: https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library.

I changed the API_ENDPOINT to wc-api/v2/ and I added this function:

```
public function create_order( $data ) {
    return $this->_make_api_call( 'orders/', $data, 'POST' );
}
```

I get:

```
Warning:  rawurldecode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/class-wc-api-client-    v2.php on line 441
Warning:  rawurldecode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/class-wc-api-client-v2.php on line 441
  object(stdClass)#1801 (1) {
 ["errors"]=>
 array(1) {
   [0]=>
   object(stdClass)#1798 (2) {
     ["code"]=>
     string(3) "401"
     ["message"]=>
     string(19) "cURL HTTP error 401"
   }
 }
}
```

I am using the following code to call create_order

```
$data = array(
    "status" => "processing",
    "payment_details" => array("method_id" => "paypal", "method_title" => "PayPal", "paid" => 1),
    "line_items" => array("id" => 123, "subtotal" => 45.00, "total" => 45.00, "total_tax" => 0.00, "price" => 45.00, "quantity" => 1, "name" => "itemName", "product_id" => 123)
);
var_dump($wc_api->create_order($data));
```

Any help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I didn't work with WooCommerce API or the API client you mentioned, the first thing I noticed was **cURL HTTP error 401**, probably authentication error. Please double check consumer key & secret.

Second thing was warning produced in **rawurldecode()** function (method). You're passing array but the function is expecting string. So check that part carefully as well.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll just wait for them to update their php client library!

Answer (score 1):

At present the rawurlencode issue is present both on the API and in the library you're using

The authentication error is because your endpoint is 'orders/', it should be 'orders' (no slash)

Comment: Thanks for your response!

They've actually documented the v2 api now, so that's really helpful in fixing all of this.

http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#introduction